# Live updating from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file which is dynamically and contain match info including an unique id. The JSON is divided into 3 arrays live, upcoming and recent. Since i'm quite new to Javascript i'm wondering what would be the best way to go in order to make this livescore script. I need it to be updating without refreshing browser? What is my options? Maybe someone has a snippet?

The JSON is automatically updates through another script which is connected to a cron job, so the script does not need to do anything regarding the JSON. Only retrieve and show the data.

I'm using dreamhost, which gives me access to shell, so websockets and so on is an option.

Comment: Please state some more information such as server supports Websocket/longpolling or general Ajax call.There are some way to achieve that and the best solution is all depends on the server side structure for pushing(sending) json data.

Comment: Everything should be possible since i have access to shell.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a jquery user to give you a snippit for this one, but in vanilla ecmascript 6, you use an XMLHttpRequest object to get the JSON from your server. This object can request data from the server asynchronously and is triggered by the client/browser so you can update the live match info when and as often as you like. You would just have to write a function to replace the data on the webpage with the new info when it is updated.

Comment: If it replace the data after a specific interval wouldnt that create bad user experience since it would remove the matches and then show them again? or would that not be visible to the user?

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't easily have the data swap in place. I would use
`element.innerHTML = matchdata['match']['score'];`
or something similar to that, it will leave the element in the html document, but change the text inside it.
Adding new matches, or removing finished matches would be more difficult, but you could have old ones stay in place and turn grey to indicate they've ended, and new ones appear on the end of the list.